# Curve fitting differential equations in Python

Tags: python-2.7, physics, curve-fitting, differential-equations

I have a curve of >1000 points that I would like to fit to a differential equation in the form of x'' = (a*x'' + b x' + c x + d), where a,b,c,d are constants. How would I proceed in doing this using Python 2.7?

Comment: Try to solve it analytically, then plot it for different a,b,c,d and initial conditions. Any analytical curve brings thousand more time information than any computed curve. This type of diff.eq. is rather easy to solve and there is a chapter on those kind of homogenous eq-s in any book on diff.eq.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you intend to have the third derivative on the right.

Group your data in relatively small bins, possibly overlapping. For each bin, compute a cubic approximation of the data. From that compute the derivatives in the center point of the group. With the derivatives of all groups you now have a classical linear regression problem.

If the samples are equally spaced, you might try to move the problem into frequency space via FFT. A sensible truncation of the data might be a problem here. In the frequency space, the task reduces to a polynomial linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

You could use optimization to find the best parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` that minimize the difference between the measured and predicted values. Here is example code with a 3rd-order differential equation in [gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that I develop.

[image: optimized solution]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

t_data = [0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.8,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4]
x_data = [2.0,1.6,1.2,0.7,0.3,0.15,0.1,\
          0.05,0.03,0.02,0.015,0.01]

m = GEKKO()
m.time = t_data

# states
x = m.CV(value=x_data); x.FSTATUS = 1  # fit to measurement
y,z = m.Array(m.Var,2,value=0)

# adjustable parameters
a,b,c,d = m.Array(m.FV,4)
a.STATUS=1; b.STATUS=1; c.STATUS=1; d.STATUS=1 

# differential equation
#      Original:  x''' = a*x'' + b x' + c x + d
#      Transform: y = x'
#                 z = y'
#                 z' = a*z + b*y + c*x + d
m.Equations([y==x.dt(),z==y.dt()])
m.Equation(z.dt()==a*z+b*y+c*x+d) # differential equation

m.options.IMODE = 5   # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 3   # collocation nodes
m.solve(disp=False)   # display solver output
print(a.value[0],b.value[0],c.value[0],d.value[0])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # plot solution
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'bo',label='Predicted')
plt.plot(m.time,x_data,'rx',label='Measured')
plt.legend(); plt.xlabel('Time'), plt.ylabel('Value'); plt.show()
```

Most differential equation solvers require that you transform higher-order derivatives into separate first-order derivative equations. This is easy to do as you need to define a new state for every additional order (2nd and 3rd derivatives) as [shown here](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/2ndOrderDifferential).